# Is this some sort of disease?

Tags: diseases

I do not see that on all plants. But some plants have this near each leaf. Is this some disease?

[image]

(Red Amaranth)

Comment: No, its just part of the plant, I think its where the flower emerges.

Comment: But I do not see that on other samples of the same specie. why only this one?

Comment: If you google lots of images, you will see some plants have them.    Possibly when they are ready to flower, depending on the conditions they have been treated to.  It is absolutely, positively not a disease.